# Python Numpy array> assigning string values and boolean comparison

Tags: python, string, numpy, boolean

```
import numpy as np
```

I have this numpy array:

```
data = np.array(data)
# assume it has x number of rows and y columns
```

1) At one point I replace the 10th column values as follows with string value:

```
data[data[0::,10] == "C",10] = "0"
```

2) In a for loop with index **i**, I do this comparison by converting the string to float-

```
x = (data[0::,10].astype(np.float) == i)
```

This throws a ValueError: could not convert string to float:

Why?

Comment: Can you verify all other string values in 10th column are present (non-empty strings) and are numeric?

Comment: I have edited the original post to say the I am concerned with the 10th column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your error message there is some `''` (empty string) in the column you are trying to convert.
Be sure that the column you are comparing has only strings that ar convertible to float. You can create a `isfloat()` function to do that for you:

```
def isfloat(x):
    try:
        float(x)
        return True
    except:
        return False
isfloat = np.vectorize(isfloat)
```

Then use in your example:

```
data[ data[:,col] == 'C', col ] = '0'

x = (data[ isfloat(data[:,col]), col ].astype(np.float) == i)
```

Comment: @Selvam when you create a function in Python you can pass some arguments. `x` is an argument of the function `isfloat()`

Comment: Thanks. And what is happening in this line isfloat = np.vectorize(isfloat) ?

Comment: the `isfloat()` function words only for single values, when you do `isfloat = np.vectorize(isfloat)` you redefine the function using `numpy.vectorize` which is equivalent than implementing a Python for loop over the an array of floats, making the new `isfloat()` applicable to an array...